# how to update-or-create an object in/into a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `User` class that can store a list of answers and lessons

```
  has_many :answers
  has_many :lessons, :through => :answers
```

The answer class:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :lesson

    attr_accessible :finished, :current_solution
end
```

Every time the user works on a lesson, I want to store his latest answer. I tried to do it like this:

```
if current_user
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  @code = request.request_parameters["code"]
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  begin     # retrieve an old answer, if possible
    @answer = Answer.find [params[:id], session[:user_id]]
  rescue
  end
  if not @answer  # else create a new one
    @answer = Answer.new
    @answer.lesson_id = @lesson.id
    @answer.user_id = @user.id
    @user.answers << @answer  # store it in the user's answers list
  end

  @validation_passed = @lesson.validate( @code ) 
  @answer.finished = @validation_passed # update answer
  @answer.current_solution = @code
```

database schema:

```
  create_table "answers", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "lesson_id",        :null => false
    t.integer "user_id",          :null => false
    t.string  "finished"
    t.string  "current_solution"
  end

  add_index "answers", ["lesson_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_answers_on_lesson_id_and_user_id", :unique => true
```

I get an exception `columns lesson_id, user_id are not unique`, or `columns lesson_id, user_id are not unique: INSERT INTO "answers" ("current_solution", "finished", "lesson_id", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`, but I don't understand why that can happen, as I only create a new object if none can be found with the according coordinates..

I'd be glad if anybody could tell me what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query to find the `Answer` from params is not correct - it should be:

```
@answer = Answer.find_by_lesson_id_and_user_id(@lesson.id, @user.id)
```

You can also skip the `begin`-`rescue`-`end` block when doing it this way.

And you can simplify this further if you search on the associations:

```
@answer = @user.answers.where(:lesson_id => @lesson).first
```

Moreover, you can add a scope to the `Answer` class if this is a common lookup:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_lesson, lambda{ |lesson| where(:lesson_id => lesson) }
end
```

And then you can simplify this to:

```
@answer = @user.answers.for_lesson(@lesson).first
```

Comment: thanks for these nice ways of retrieving the answer :)  the exception is gone by now, but unfortunately, the changes made in the fields answer.finished and answer.current_solution are not permanently stored... their content is not there any more when I re-visit an application I already worked on :(

Comment: correct - you need to call `@answer.save` (or `@answer.save!` if you're not feeling as brave) to commit these changes to the database after you set them

Comment: I have already tried that, but this throws an exception `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: answers.: UPDATE "answers" SET "finished" = 't', "current_solution" = '1' WHERE "answers"."" IS NULL`. This IS NULL is strange..

Comment: @chrissy: agreed - that UPDATE statement is strange.  Primarily because it thinks the primary key is a blank string (?!) - any idea why this might be so?  Can you confirm that your 'answers' table has an 'id' column?

Comment: Oh you are right! :) I realized that there is no id, but only `add_index "answers", ["lesson_id", "user_id"]`. I thought, this would create an composite primary key, but it obviously doesn't. After having added an ID, it works :)  Thanks a lot! :)